# How to run FsCheck with Xunit

Tags: f#, xunit, xunit.net, f#-fake, fscheck

Hi I am trying to run `FsCheck.Xunit` tests with `xunit.runner.console` and getting the following exception:

```
Kata.TennisProperties.Given advantaged player when advantaged player wins score is correct [FAIL]
  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ---- System.Exception : The type Kata.Tennis+Player is not handled automatically by FsCheck. Consider using another type or writing and registering a generator for it.
  Stack Trace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
```

I am trying to follow [Mark Seemann's talk](https://vimeo.com/162036084).  My setup is as follows:

I have a single library type project whith two files. One with the code to be tested and one with the test code. The project compile just fine. I am not using the VS IDE but just VSCode text editor with Ionide plugin for F#.

I have tried with various setups with and without `FSharp.Core` nuget installs, with and without version specification of `FSharp.Core`.

Any idea where to look further? I am running out of ideas and getting frustrated. I've already spent two days on this. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed this by adding the `app.config` file bellow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <Paket>True</Paket>
      <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

I did this before but using VSCode + Ionide didn't got the config file added to the project. So, very important, don't forget to add the `app.config` file to the project also. It is not enough to just create the file in project folder.

Comment: Do you have a repo up somewhere that's viewable?

Comment: I was following this article [tennis kata](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/02/10/types-properties-software-designing-with-types/) up to a point. I have uploded to gh at your request. Here is the link: https://github.com/adicirstei/tennis-kata-tut